# Where is the sqoop library directory?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

To install the MySQL connector in Sqoop I need to put the jar file in the Sqoop directory but I cannot find it (it is not in `/usr/lib/sqoop`).
I installed Sqoop with Cloudera on multiple machines.

Where can I find the Sqoop directory on one of the machines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using Ubuntu ?
In this case it may be a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/something...` (check with ls -la)

Comment: Great! Thanks. Indeed, I finally manage to trace the sqoop lib: `ls -la  /usr/bin/sqoop` pointed me to `/etc/alternatives/sqoop`, then `ls -la  /etc/alternatives/sqoop` all the way to `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10/bin/sqoop`. My libs were in `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10/lib/sqoop`

Comment: And the full location for CDH5.1.2 is `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.2-1.cdh5.1.2.p0.3/lib/sqoop/lib`